# How can I automate conditional formatting formals in Google Sheets based on the cell I am formatting without referencing it specifically?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I've got a conditional formatting function in Google Sheets which essentially checks if the cell I am formatting is equal to any one of a range of other cells.

Take this - the cell I am formatting is A5. Now, if anything inputted into the range J7:J11 is equal to the text in A5, the cell should be formatted.

Currently, the function I have for this is =XOR(J7=A5, J8=A5, J9=A5, J10=A5, J11=A5) and it will format if this outputs TRUE.

The problem with this is that I have to keep copying and pasting conditional formatting rules for 175 different cells which are in a situation similar to A5, and for each, I have to scroll through and manually change the numbers of each cell number in the formula for every single box.

Is there a way to make this faster by, for example, making the function reference the targeted cell which I am formatting without explicitly saying what that is?

Technically, what I am doing now works, it's just absurdly slow and probably has a much better way of doing it that I am unaware of.

Sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boVrlzIVEKFO_tcfqQZ1PfzEQ_la-TUUl7h2ZlDICOs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am sure there is better way than doing it manually, but you should upload sample data and desired output as now it is not clear what "similar situation" means.

Comment: Here's a sample sheet you can view/edit. I made a formatting rule in cell A2 to demonstrate how A2 itself is present in the formatting formula (this would be similar to the rest of the A2:A13 range but I am not going to waste time putting formulas on all of them). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boVrlzIVEKFO_tcfqQZ1PfzEQ_la-TUUl7h2ZlDICOs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check you file, I made changes to conditional formatting. Look at the new range (A2:A13)  and ABSOLUTE references to $A$16:$B$17. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, seems to be working fine. Didn't think conditional formatting would change the checked cell value if applied to a range. Thanks very much.

Comment: In this case absolute references are key. If you leave relative references then A2 will be compared to A16:B17, A3 to A17:B18, A4 to A18:B19 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I've put solution to "suggested logic" tab. Please check.

1. Add a column with this arrayformula:

   ```
   =arrayformula(iferror(find(upper(A2:A13), textjoin("|", TRUE, upper($A$16:$B$17)))))
   ```
2. Conditional formatting formula:

   ```
   =isblank(B2) = FALSE
   ```

The formulae helps you highlight cells with content containing one of the data in criteria range.

Also included a tab "Improved UI" to show how we can add conditional formatting and criteria in a more "sustainable" way.

Comment: Also included a tab "Improved UI" to show how we can add conditional formatting and criteria in a more "sustainable" way

Comment: Please do not use the comment space to add info; edit & update your post instead.